# What does $H_*(X,A) = 0$ intuitively mean?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, group-isomorphism

So i am really a novice in terms of homology theory, and i just recently read about the relative homology groups. I have a question i couln't answer myself and i hope someone can help me getting a better understanding.

Let $X$ be a top. space and $A \subset X$ a subspace. What exactly does $$H_*(X,A) = 0$$ tell me intuitively? 
I know that if we have $H_*(X,A) = 0$, the inclusion $\iota: A \to X$ induces an isomorphism $\iota_*:H_*(A) \to H_*(X)$ <s>from which i conclude that $A$ and $X$ are homotopy equivalent spaces.</s>

Is there anything else i should be able to conclude from the given information that $H_*(X,A) = 0$ ?

Or asked differently, let's say i've been given a top. space $X$ and a subspace $A \subset X$ and let's assume $A$ is a deformation retract of $X$.

Can i immediately conclude that $X_*(X,A) = 0$? Or does this not hold in general?

Highly appreciating any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think you can conclude that $A$ and $X$ are homotopy equivalent from that.

Comment: Hi Randall, thanks for your reply. I might indeed be mistaken, sorry. But the other inclusion holds, doesnt it? I.e. homotopy equivalent spaces do have isomorphic homology groups, don't they?

Comment: Yes, that is true.  The converse is far from it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the inclusion of $A$ in $X$ is nice enough*, then outside degree zero, the relative homology is the same as the homology of the quotient $X/A$. In this case, the vanishing just means that $X/A$ is acyclic.

*there needs to be an open neighborhood of $A$ in $X$ which deformation retracts to $A$. I don't know an intuitive way of thinking about it if that's not the case!

Comment: thank you @hunter. can you tell me whether the condition in my second question i asked might be true? (last paragraph)

Comment: @Zest That's right. If $X$ deformation retracts to $A$, then $X/A$ deformation retracts to a point so is acyclic.

Comment: beautiful, thank you very much!